# Boostrap.css making layout 100% width/height

Tags: html, css

I am currently working with bootsrap and a simple chat layout. I have been able to modify it to my needs for the most part. The only problem is that the layout does not adapt to the window size(100% height/width). I would like to make use of the whole page. All elements lie within a div called `container`. How could I get this to adapt to the page  (100% height/width)? [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bullseye2346/pen/KkJEH)

```
.conversation-wrap
{
    box-shadow: -2px 0 3px #ddd;
    padding:0;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.conversation
{
    padding:5px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    margin:0;

}

.message-wrap
{
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ddd;
    padding:0;

}
.msg
{
    padding:5px;
    /*border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;*/
    margin:0;
}
.msg-wrap
{
    padding:10px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;

}
```

Comment: what if you remove class `container` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a col-lg-12 to your container

```
<div class="container col-lg-12">
...
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ucrog

Edit : Also change

```
<div class="message-wrap col-lg-8">
```

to

```
<div class="message-wrap col-lg-9">
```